# Evaluating $a(b + c)$ more accurately with FMA

Tags: floating-point, computer-arithmetic, machine-precision

I'm using machine-precision floating-point arithmetic, and every so often it happens that I need to evaluate an expression of the form $a(b + c)$. I found that the accuracy can be improved using [FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add) (fused multiply-add), using one of these two forms:

1. $fma(a, b, a c)$
2. $fma(a, c, a b)$

Sometimes the first form is more accurate, and sometimes it's the second one.

Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$ belong to some floating-point format, I'd like conditions on $a$, $b$, $c$ to determine when the first form is the more accurate one, and when it's the second form.

Comment: Didn't know about this operation. At your link they talk about $a+(b\times c)$, that is different from $a(b+c)$

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo Yes. Mathematically, $a(b + c) = ab + ac = fma(a, b, ac) = fma(a, c, ab)$.

Comment: I understand, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response doesn't specify conditions on $a$, $b$ or $c$ but does describe how you might go about computing the result you seek regardless of their values.

Let the exact sum of $b$ and $c$ be represented by $s$ and $t$, where $s$ and $t$ are floating-point numbers with $|t| <= ulp(s)/2$.  (E.g., use the well-known `2Sum` algorithm; see [1].)  Thus $a(b + c)$ is exactly $a(s + t)$.  Since $|s|$ is much larger than $|t|$, we can approximate the computation of $a(s + t)$ by `fma(a, s, a * t)`.

Sample code might be

```
double f(double a, double b, double c) {
    double s = b + c;
    double t = (b - (s - c)) + (c - (s - (s - c)));
    return fma(a, s, a * t);
}
```

EDITED TO ADD:

Because the value of $a(s + t)$ is very close to $a \times s$ (recall: $|a * t| <= ulp(a * s)/2$), $a \times t$ is a relatively small correction term. Since `fma(a, s, a * t)` involves calculating $a \times s$ exactly without rounding and then adding $a * t$, it provides a very good approximation to $a(s + t)$.

If one were to calculate `fma(a, t, a * s)` instead, one would be calculating $a \times t$ exactly and then adding `a * s` (the rounded value of $a \times s$).  Because of the relative magnitudes of $a * s$ and $a \times t$, this is essentially the same as calculating `(a * s) + (a * t)`.  In this case, no use is made of the additional precision provided by the `fma` operation.

I think the key is to visualize the alignment shift that takes place when, in `fma(x, y, z)`, the addition of $z$ with the exact product of $x$ and $y$ is performed. In the case at hand, we want $x \times y$ to be the larger quantity so that $z$ is "shifted to the right" when the addition is performed.

END OF EDIT

[1] J.-M. Muller and L. Rideau, “Formalization of double-word arithmetic, and comments on ”Tight and rigorous error bounds for basic building blocks of double-word arithmetic”,” ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, vol. 48, no. 1, pp. 1–24, Mar. 2022, doi: 10.1145/3484514.  https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02972245

Comment: "Since $|s|$ is much larger than $|t|$, we can approximate the computation of $a(s + t)$ by `fma(a, s, a * t)`." Two questions: (1) Are `fma(a, s, a * t)` and `fma(a, t, a * s)` equivalent in this case? (2) Could you expand on how $|s|$ being much larger than $|t|$ implies that this is OK?

Comment: See my attempt to clarify above.

Answer (score 1):

For accurate computation one must distinguish three rather than two cases. If $b$ and $c$ are close in magnitude, but of opposite sign, subtractive cancellation occurs. Neither of the two $fma$-based expressions will deliver an accurate result in that case. However, this case is easily handled based on the [Sterbenz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterbenz_lemma), which states that $x\ominus y = x -y$ if $\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{x}{y} \le 2$, that is, the floating-point subtraction delivers the exact mathematical result in this case. To compute $p = a (b + c)$, we can use the following algorithm:

```
r := b ÷ c   
IF (r ≤ -½) AND (r ≥ -2) 
  p := (b + c) · a;
ELSE IF |b| > |c|
  p := fma (a, b, a · c)
ELSE
  p := fma (a, c, a · b)
END IF
```

In the absence of floating-point overflow and underflow in intermediate computation, this should deliver results with a maximum error of 1 [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). This compares to a maximum error of slightly over 0.5 ulp for the algorithm from [JM Arnold's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4619931/114200). A maximum error of 1.5 ulp can be achieved without any case distinctions by using Kahan's algorithm for the accurate computation of the sum of products, $s =uv+xy$.

Jean-Michel Muller, "On the Error of Computing ab+cd using Cornea,
Harrison and Tang's Method", *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*,
Vol. 41, No.2, Article 7, (January 2015)

Specializing Kahan's algorithm to the computation of $p = ab+ac$ results in the following sequence of four operations:

```
w := a · c
e := fma (a, -c, w)
f := fma (a, b, w)
p := f - e
```